# difficulty in multidimensional pointers in c?

Tags: c, pointers

I have a C program that uses pointers but I am not able to understand the output. Why is the first output `1` and the other is `210`. They are both pointers to a 3 dimensional array.

I'm not able to find a solution

```
int main() {    
    char arr[5][7][6];    
    char (*p)[5][7][6] = &arr;    
    printf("%d\n", (&arr + 1) - &arr);    
    printf("%d\n", (char *)(&arr + 1) - (char *)&arr);    
    printf("%d\n", (unsigned)(arr + 1) - (unsigned)arr);    
    printf("%d\n", (unsigned)(p + 1) - (unsigned)p);    
    return 0;    
}
```

the first output is `1` and the last is `210`

Comment: What did you expect instead of 1 and 210 and why?

Comment: their value should be same both first and second as they are both pointer to the three dimensional same array so answer for both should be 210 naa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C does pointer arithmetic in units of the pointed-to type.

In `(&arr + 1) - &arr`, `&arr` is the address of a `char [5][7][6]` (an array of 5 arrays of 7 arrays of 6 `char`). Then `&arr +1` is the address of one `char [5][7][6]` beyond `&arr` and `(&arr + 1) - &arr` is distance from `&arr` to `&arr + 1` measured in units of `char [5][7][6]`, so the distance is one unit.

In `(char *)(&arr + 1) - (char *)&arr)`, the two addresses are converted to `char *`, so the arithmetic is done in units of `char`. So the result is the distance from `&arr` to `&arr + 1` measured in units of `char`. Since the distance from `&arr` to `&arr + 1` is one `char [5][7][6]`, it is 5•7•6 `char`, which is 210 `char`, so the result is 210.

### Incidentals

Do not use `%d` to print the results of subtracting pointers. When two pointers are subtracted, the type of the result is `ptrdiff_t`, and it may be printed with `%td`, as in `printf("%td\n", (&arr + 1) - &arr));`.

To convert pointers to integers, it is preferable to use `uintptr_t`, defined in `<stdint.h>`, rather than `unsigned`.

To print `unsigned` values, use `%u`, not `%d`.

To print `uintptr_t` values, include `<inttypes.h>` and use `"%" PRIuPTR`, as in `printf("%" PRIuPTR "\n", (uintptr_t) (p + 1) - (uintptr_t) p);`.

Comment: sir can u explain why unsigned also give 210.is it the unsigned int so shouldn't it be divided by 4.just confused a bit

Comment: @HarshChaturvedi: When an address is converted to an integer type such as `unsigned`, most C implementations simply reinterpret the memory address as an integer, effectively producing a byte address. (The C standard allows flexibility for other things.) When the two integer values are subtracted, the difference is simply the difference in bytes.

Answer (score 2):

First, it's not safe to use `%d` to print pointer differences, which have type `ptrdiff_t` (which is a signed version of `size_t`).

Ignoring that, you have the following declarations:

```
char arr[5][7][6];
char (*p)[5][7][6] = &arr;
```

When subtracting two pointers, result is divided by the size of the target (i.e., the inverse of what happens when you add an integer to a pointer, in which case the integer is scaled by the size).

For the first example:

```
(&arr + 1) - &arr
```

Here both `&arr` and `&arr + 1` have type `char (*)[5][7][6]`, so the size of what they point to is `sizeof(char [5][7][6])`.  The pointer addition multiplies `1` by this size, and the pointer subtraction divides the difference by this size, canceling it out.  So the result is `1`, regardless of the target size.

For the second example:

```
(char *)(&arr + 1) - (char *)&arr
```

Here the pointer addition again multiplies 1 by `sizeof(char [5][7][6])`, which is `sizeof(char)*5*7*6`, i.e. `1*5*7*6` which is `210`.  But the subtraction divides by `sizeof(char)` which is `1`.  So the result is `210`.

For the third example:

```
(unsigned)(arr + 1) - (unsigned)arr
```

The effect of the `unsigned` casts is similar to the effect of the `char *` casts in the previous example.  However, in this one two pointers are `arr` and `arr + 1`.  In this context, the array types "decay" to the pointer types `char (*)[7][6]`.  The size of the pointer target is therefore `sizeof(char)*7*6` i.e. `1*7*6` which is `42`.  So the result is `42`.

Finally, for the last example:

```
(unsigned)(p + 1) - (unsigned)p)
```

Both `p` and `p + 1` have type `char (*)[5][7][6]`, so the target size is `210`.  The `unsigned` casts again result in straight address subtraction, with no division applied to the result.  So the result is `210`.

Answer (score 1):

```
char (*p)[5][7][6] = &arr;
```

Here p is an array of pointers to chars, not a pointer to an array of chars.

```
printf("%d\n", (&arr + 1) - &arr);
```

& sign returns address. you are doing math on addresses not values! and anything plus 1 and minus itself will result in 1

```
(unsigned)p
```

this casting behavior is not guaranteed and is not safe to do. and you are not dereferencing your pointer anywhere.

You should read more about pointers, types and casting and operator priority before doing this.

I recommend this two videos by Brian Will:

[the C language (part 2 of 5)](https://youtu.be/9wydl0VFmeQ)

[the C language (part 5 of 5)](https://youtu.be/3xpgXW_DYL0)